# Что такое "Вращение в Кватернионах"?

Tags: blender

За что отвечает графа "Вращение в Кватернионах"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменение значения само по себе ни к чему не приводит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при общем изменение/вращение кости - значение тоже меняется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кватернионы это альтернатива вращению в углах. Углы в принципе неидеальны, например из-за [Gimbal Lock](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA), когда при вращении оси складываются и теряется степень свободы. В принципе не существует идеальной системы вращения, поэтому существуют альтернативные варианты, такие как кватернионы.

Прежде всего разделите в своем сознании углы Эйлера и кватернионы, углы измеряются в градусах и радианах, кватернионы  больше похожи на 4-хмерный вектор, и W-составляющая имеет такое-же значение как остальные три. X,Y,Z и W - равноценны.

Лучше всего эту тему расписывает [James Grime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BR8tK-LuB0), если вы понимаете по-английски. Если это не совсем понятно опишу так.

Представьте себе 3-хмерный вектор. Это не кватернион, однако похож на него:
[image: введите сюда описаие изображения]

Угол, который образует вектор с вертикальными и горизонтальными плоскостями, можно выразить через этот вектор. Однако, в отличие от кватерниона, нельзя выразить поворот вектора вокруг своей оси. Вообще сравнение кватерниона и вектора некорректно с точки зрения математики, но мы опустим это и рассмотрим второй пример, допустим, координаты вектора 0,0,1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нетрудно догадаться, что вектор с такими координатами смотрит вертикально вверх. Теперь вектор 0,0,2. Каким образом он ориентирован? Абсолютно так-же. Да, он длиннее, но поворот такой-же. Таким образом, как ни масштабируй вектор, он не будет поворачиваться. Точно так-же и вы, изменяя W-составную кватерниона изменяете его длину, но не поворот. Отметим так-же что тоже самое будет и с кватернионами 1,0,0,0; 0,1,0,0; 0,0,1,0 и 0,0,0,1, так как X,Y,Z,W - равноценны.

Это свойство верно и для кватернионов. Вы увеличиваете одну часть комплекстного числа, это меняет "величину", но не поворот.

Вы можете подумать, что кватернионы содержат излишнюю информацию, возможно это и так. Но их любят в программировании за то что можно повернуть на нужный угол объект, каким бы самым сложным образом он бы был не развернут, просто перемножив кватернионы друг на друга.

[Сравнение анимации поворота через углы Эйлера и кватернионы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKh831EqR7Q)

Почему же когда вы поворачиваете объект, W меняется?

Поворот в системе кватернионов выполняется умножением одного кватерниона на другой. А любой поворот не равный 90 градусам всегда выражен как минимум 2мя составляющими. Вот вам и изменение 2х частей одновременно.

См так-же:

[Статья на википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

[Что такое кватернион — объяснение человеческим языком](https://blog2k.ru/archives/1124)

[Кватернионы для чайников](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/107998/)

[Каверзные кватернионы](https://habr.com/ru/post/183908/)